# Sequence Generator while migrating from Hibernate 4.1.2 to Hibernate 5.2.17

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to migrate an application to new version of all the frameworks. But while migrating Hibernate from version 4.1.2 to version 5.2.17 I have encountered some strange behaviour (I am also using Oracle 12).

The definition of the ID is as follow:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "LOCATION_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOCATION")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LOCATION_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, precision = EntityColumnDefinitions.PRECISION_19)
private Long id;
```

I saw that this code is not using the sequence provided but some Hibernate generated sequence id. For this reason the sequence in the database is out of sync with the id.
I could repair this by adding "allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1" to the ID definition and creating a PL-SQL-Script for updating the sequence and putting it in sync with the ID.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "LOCATION_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_LOCATION", allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LOCATION_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, precision = EntityColumnDefinitions.PRECISION_19)
private Long id;
```

My question is - Is it possible to use same mechanismus as in version 4.1.2? I mean which is the ID Annotation in order to use same Hibernate generated sequence id based on last id in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this setting in the persistence.xml file will do the trick:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
```

Maybe this will save some time to someone else.